# Mit Hand detection runs fine but is not able to detect hand

Tags: ros, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am able to run hand_interaction  without any issue .But after it detects a human on the on the prime sense user tracker view it always shows "looking for pose" on the detected human.Is there any specific pose link the openni_tracker .plz help
the below is the copy of terminal window running hand _interaction.

I have some error like
"libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/001/014: Permission denied.
libusb requires write access to USB device nodes. "
which i have solved

but i still am not able to find why it is not able to detect hand

roslaunch hand_interaction hand_detector.launch
... logging to /home/usr1/.ros/log/7cfb26b2-8555-11e1-975c-38607793109f/roslaunch-CrevaviWS2-1004.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://CrevaviWS2:50763/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /rosdistro
- /openni_node1/use_indices
- /openni_node1/depth_registration
- /openni_node1/image_time_offset
- /openni_node1/depth_frame_id
- /openni_node1/depth_mode
- /openni_node1/debayering
- /rosversion
- /openni_node1/projector_depth_baseline
- /openni_node1/rgb_frame_id
- /openni_node1/depth_rgb_translation
- /openni_node1/depth_time_offset
- /openni_node1/image_mode
- /openni_node1/shift_offset
- /openni_node1/device_id
- /openni_node1/depth_rgb_rotation

NODES
/
openni_node1 (openni_camera/openni_node)
kinect_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
kinect_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
kinect_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
kinect_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
handdetector (hand_interaction/detectskelhands)
ressetter (dynamic_reconfigure/dynparam)
skel_tracker (skeletal_tracker/tracker)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [1019]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 7cfb26b2-8555-11e1-975c-38607793109f
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [1035]
started core service [/rosout]
process[openni_node1-2]: started with pid [1047]
process[kinect_base_link-3]: started with pid [1048]
process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started with pid [1049]
process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started with pid [1050]
process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started with pid [1057]
process[handdetector-7]: started with pid [1061]
process[ressetter-8]: started with pid [1068]
process[skel_tracker-9]: started with pid [1077]
Waiting for service /openni_camera/set_parameters...
libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/001/014: Permission denied.
libusb requires write access to USB device nodes.
libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/001/014: Permission denied.
libusb requires write access to USB device nodes.
[ INFO] [1334313803.349585002]: [/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1334313803.349783723]: [/openni_node1] 1. device on bus 001:14 is a unknown (2ae) from unknown (45e) with serial id ''
[ INFO] [1334313803.352306759]: [/openni_node1] searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1334313803.410848582]: [/openni_node1] Opened 'unknown' on bus 1:14 with serial number ''
[ INFO] [1334313803.424991158]: rgb_frame_id = '/openni_rgb_optical_frame'
[ INFO] [1334313803.427352438]: depth_frame_id = '/openni_depth_optical_frame'
New User 1
Lost user 1
New User 1
Lost user 1
New User 1
New User 2
Lost user 1
Lost user 2
New User 2
Lost user 2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31746/mit-hand-detection-runs-fine-but-is-not-able-to--detect-hand/) by [narenayak](https://answers.ros.org/users/1334/narenayak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Nernayak,

When the program shows the message "looking for pose" you should go in front of the kinect sensor and pose like this:

[image description http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-t9FxKt9JUts/TWfK4juSF7I/AAAAAAAABBI/36-uvouIG7I/s320/PsiPose.gif](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-t9FxKt9JUts/TWfK4juSF7I/AAAAAAAABBI/36-uvouIG7I/s320/PsiPose.gif)

Once the skeleton is calibrated you will be able to detect the hands.

Best regards,
Martin.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3